# How to finalize the parts of the string that have already have been changed?

Tags: java

I'm doing a cryptography project in my class and I am having struggles with replacing the letters of a string.

This is what I have so far, which ends up replacing the letters that already have been changed and I
need the changed letters to stay constant.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static String alphabet = "ABCDElFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static String key = "CFILORUXADGJMPSVYBEHKNQTWZcfiloruxadgjmpsvybehknqtwz";

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Phrase :: ");
        String text = keyboard.nextLine();
        goEncrypt(text);
        }

    private static String goEncrypt(String text) {
        String Encrypt = text;
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            char ALPHABET = alphabet.charAt(i);
            char KEY = key.charAt(i);
            Encrypt = Encrypt.replace(ALPHABET, KEY);
            System.out.println(Encrypt);
        }
        return Encrypt;
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: To keep the changed letters rather it becoming changed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this task the wrong way around.  Instead of looping through alphabet, you need to loop through text, replacing one character at a time.  That way you hit each character once.

Comment: I'm having troubles of coming up with a way to loop through the text and replace the letters. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm starting to think if being placed in Ap computer science without joining pre-ap is a curse or a blessing.

Comment: You are better off doing it yourself.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your code to use a map of alphabet to key abd then scan over the incoming text:

```
public static Map<char, char> keyMap = new HashMap<char, char>();
static
{
    keyMap.put('A', 'C');
    ...
}
...
private static String goEncrypt(String text) {
    StringBuffer encrypt = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        encrypt.append(keyMap.get(text.charAt(i)));
    }
    return encrypt.toString();
}
```